# Are locks required for all MPI calls when using MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED in multithread enviroment?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, mpi

In MPI multithread enviroment MPI calls should be protected with mutex (or other thread-lock mechanism) when we initialize **MPI_Init_thread** with **MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED** (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811416/proper-use-of-mpi-thread-serialized-with-pthreads/6987529#6987529)). This is not required with **MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE**, but this is not supported by all MPI implementations.

My question is whether a lock is absolutely required for some MPI functions, specifically for **MPI_Test**, **MPI_Wait** and **MPI_Get_count**. I know the lock is required for all MPI calls "with communication" (such as **MPI_Gather**, **MPI_Bcast**, **MPI_Send**, **MPI_Recv**, **MPI_Isend**, **MPI_Irecv**, etc), but I suspect that this lock is not required for other functions, such as **MPI_Get_count**, that is a local function. I need to know if this lock is required or not for functions like **MPI_Test**, **MPI_Wait**, **MPI_Get_count**, **MPI_Probe** and **MPI_Iprobe** (I do not know which of these are local functions and which ones are not). Is this lock-depedency defined in the MPI Standard or is it implementation-defined?

I am developing a parallelization library with non-blocking MPI calls mixed with C++11 threads, and I need use **MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED** to support the most MPI implementations. **MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE** is also implemented (better performance in most cases) in the library, but the **MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED** support is also required.

In the next simple example code, is required the lock before the **MPI_Test** call?

```cpp
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

static std::mutex mutex;
const static int numThreads = 4;
static int rank;
static int nprocs;

static void rthread(const int thrId) {
    int recv_buff[2];
    int send_buff[2];
    MPI_Request recv_request;

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mutex);     // <-- this lock is required
        MPI_Irecv(recv_buff, 2, MPI_INT, ((rank>0) ? rank-1 : nprocs-1), thrId, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &recv_request);
    }

    send_buff[0] = thrId;
    send_buff[1] = rank;
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mutex);     // <-- this lock is required
        MPI_Send(send_buff, 2, MPI_BYTE, ((rank+1<nprocs) ? rank+1 : 0), thrId, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    int flag = 0;
    while (!flag) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mutex);    // <-- is this lock required?
        MPI_Test(&recv_request, &flag, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        //...        do other stuff
    }

    std::cout << "[Rank " << rank << "][Thread " << thrId << "] Received a msg from thread " << recv_buff[0] << " from rank " << recv_buff[1] << std::endl;

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int provided;

    MPI_Init_thread(&(argc), &(argv), MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED, &provided);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for(int threadId = 0; threadId < numThreads; threadId++) {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(rthread, threadId));
    }
    for(int threadId = 0; threadId < numThreads; threadId++) {
        threads[threadId].join();
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

In my tests I executed some code without locks in **MPI_Test** and **MPI_Get_count** calls, nothing bad happened and the performance improves, but I don't know if this is ok or not.

Comment: "I executed some code without locks in MPI_Test and MPI_Get_count calls, nothing bad happened" - Just because nothing bad happened in your tests does *not* mean that nothing bad will happen on other users machines in the future. Race conditions are *a bitch* and can bite at *any* time. Also, future users may run your code on different hardware and unless you strictly abide by the guarantees specified in the standard, you do not know what results you'll get. "Works on my machine" means *Nothing*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lock is required. The standard just states briefly:

> **`MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED`** The process may be multi-threaded, and multiple
>   threads may make MPI calls, but only one at a time: MPI calls are not
>   made concurrently from two distinct threads

So there is no distinction between calls to different kinds of MPI functions. Since you aim to write portable code - otherwise you could just assume an implementation with `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` - you have to stick with the standard.

Comment: Yeah, reading in detail the MPI standard does not say anything else about it. It seems that MPI calls could use functions that are not thread-safe internally and it is necessary to serialize them. Maybe we could check if for a specific MPI implementation a certain MPI call only uses an internally thread-safe functions, but this would be out of the MPI standards and may not even be compatible with future updates of this specific MPI implementation. The conclusion is that it is necessary to perform a lock for all MPI calls, including local ones such as MPI_Get_count or MPI_Cancel.